# Хранение лайков пользователь-пользователь для быстрого чтения

Tags: база-данных, postgresql, elasticsearch, хранение-данных

**Вводные данные**

Есть dating-like сервис, где пользователи могут просматривать друг друга, а также ставить лайки и дизлайки. В сервисе есть лента рекомендация пользователей пользователю. Есть один пользователь посмотрел другого, то второй раз он его посмотреть уже не может.

Технически будут три типа реакции - view, like, dislike. Они вероятно будут храниться в БД типа Postgres в виде `from_user_id, to_user_id, reaction`. Также будет поисковой движок типа Elasticsearch, который будет генерировать ленту пользователю по какому-то набору признаков (здесь он не важен) и откидывать из нее тех пользователей, на которых реакция уже была.

То есть мы видим какие операции тут частые:

- Выборка всех реакция от пользователя чтобы передать весь этот огромный массив в Elasticsearch и отфильтровать по user_id
- Изменение реакции с view на like, dislike, то есть нужен быстрый доступ к одной такой записи `from_user_id, to_user_id, reaction`
- Нужно запрашивать список пользователей, которые поставили тебе лайк
- Нужно как-то понимать когда случился метч между пользователями и отдавать список совпадение like-like

**Варианты решения этого всего**

- Хранить массивы лайков, дизлайков, просмотров в Elasticsearch. Как по мне не очень хорошее решение хранить все там. Мы создаем дополнительную нагрузку на es при сохранении реакций, а es и так сильно занят генерацией ленты
- Хранить все в базе в записях типа `from_user_id, to_user_id, reaction`, но для моих целей это будет огромная простыня записей. Быстро ли Postgres сможет считать все это для одного пользователя, например, и сделать из этого массив? Я не специалист, но кажется что не быстро
- Хранить все в базе, но в виде `from_user_id, to_user_ids(set), reaction`

Мне не нравится ни один из вариантов и я думаю вдруг что-то упускаю

Comment: "Быстро ли Postgres сможет считать все это для одного пользователя, например, и сделать из этого массив?" Ну так сделай таблицу с парой миллионов записей, да проверь.